# Prevent Node.js repl from printing output

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

If the result of some javascript calculation is an array of 10,000 elements, the Node.js repl prints this out.  How do I prevent it from doing so?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a switch for this.

Comment: How about wrapping it in an anonymous function? What statement are you executing?

Comment: Since this is tagged `console`, try `$ node yourScript.js  > /dev/null 2>&1` to hide all output

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I had also thought to suggest that, but it's a REPL environment, redirecting all output here is not an option.

Comment: @IgorZinov'yev: fair point, I just saw the console-tag and jumped the gun a bit

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Why don't you just append `; null;` to your expression?

As in

```
new Array(10000); null;
```

which prints

```
null
```

or even shorter, use `;0;`

Answer (score 11):

Assign the result to a variable declared with `var`.  `var` statements always return `undefined`.

```
> new Array(10)
[ , , , , , , , , ,  ]

> var a = new Array(10)
undefined
```

Answer (score 9):

Node uses inspect to format the return values.  Replace inspect with a function that just returns an empty string and it won't display anything.

`require('util').inspect = function () { return '' };`

Answer (score 8):

Javascript has the `void` operator just for this special case. You can use it with any expression to discard the result.

```
> void (bigArray = [].concat(...lotsOfSmallArrays))
undefined
```

Answer (score 5):

You could start the REPL yourself and change anything that annoys you. For example you could tell it not to print `undefined` when an expression has no result. Or you could wrap the evaluation of the expressions and stop them from returning results. If you do both of these things at the same time you effectively reduce the REPL to a REL:

```
node -e '
    const vm = require("vm");
    require("repl").start({
        ignoreUndefined: true,
        eval: function(cmd, ctx, fn, cb) {
            let err = null;
            try {
                vm.runInContext(cmd, ctx, fn);
            } catch (e) {
                err = e;
            }
            cb(err);
        }
    });
'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already said in a comment to this question that you may want to wrap the execution of your command in an anonymous function. Let's say you have some repeated procedure that returns some kind of result. Like this:

```
var some_array = [1, 2, 3];

some_array.map(function(){

    // It doesn't matter what you return here, even if it's undefined
    // it will still get into the map and will get printed in the resulting map
    return arguments;
});
```

That gives us this output:

```
[ { '0': 1,
    '1': 0,
    '2': [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
  { '0': 2,
    '1': 1,
    '2': [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
  { '0': 3,
    '1': 2,
    '2': [ 1, 2, 3 ] } ]
```

But if you wrap the `map` method call into a self-invoking anonymous function, all output gets lost:

```
(function(){
    some_array.map(function() {
        return arguments;
    });
})();
```

This code will get us this output:

```
undefined
```

because the anonymous function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Appending `0;` is shorter than typing an anonymous function, as in `some_array.map(function(){return arguments;});0;`

Comment: To minimize output you can also wrap it in `Boolean()` or `typeof()`

Answer (score 0):

just do this in repl module.
this will return the output as an empty string.

```
const repl = require("repl").start({
    writer: (output)=>{
        return "";
    }
});
```