# How to call async method from node console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Bot class with async printInfo method:

```
class TradeBot {
    async printInfo() { //..... }
}
```

If I start 'node', create the object from the console and call the method:

```
>const createBot = require ('./BotFactory');
>const bot = createBot();
>bot.printInfo();
```

there is an annoying extra information appears in the console:

```
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain:
 Domain {
 domain: null,
 _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
 _eventsCount: 1,
 _maxListeners: undefined,
 members: [] } }
```

is there a way to suppress it?

'await' keyword produces an error here.

Comment: That "annoying extra information" is just what `printInfo` returns... a promise. You can't await outside of an async function (yet). You can use an async IIFE or use a promise chain.

Comment: `bot.printInfo.then(infoProbably => console.log(infoProbably))`

Comment: This is because you are using promises if your code is synchronous you can omit the async word, in the case is not, you should learn more about how to handle promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Phil, as far as I see this also returns Promise

Comment: @Phil , as far as I see this also returns Promise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That "annoying" extra info is the Promise object that `TradeBot#printInfo` returns.

The node REPL by default prints the returned value of anything you call:

```
> console.log('Hi')
Hi
undefined
> 2
2
> function hello() {
... return 5;
... }
undefined
> hello()
5
```

That is why you get the extra output.

Knowing this, we can see the question has been asked and answered before: [Prevent Node.js repl from printing output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13683577/3310334)

Simply, you can suppress the extra output by writing this line at the REPL instead:

```
bot.printInfo(), undefined;
```

If you want you can start node with an extra argument, [defining the REPL to use](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_custom_evaluation_functions), as [this answer recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18670532/3310334).

```
node -e '
    const vm = require("vm");
    require("repl").start({
        ignoreUndefined: true,
        eval: function(cmd, ctx, fn, cb) {
            let err = null;
            try {
                vm.runInContext(cmd, ctx, fn);
            } catch (e) {
                err = e;
            }
            cb(err);
        }
    });
'
```

Comment: Can also use `void bot.printInfo()`.