# Disable Node REPL pre-evaluation?

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

In the Node (v16.7.0) REPL, Node tries to evaluate my statement before I've finished typing it. For example, if I type `2 + 2`, it displays a faint `4` on the next line *before* I hit the Enter key. Is there a way to disable this behavior? For most cases, it's not a problem; but when I'm performing expensive operations, the REPL lags or freezes up as I'm trying to finish typing my statement. To be clear, the problem is *not* that the interpreter is printing the output; it's that it's trying to evaluate my statement before I finish typing it. Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Node.js repl from printing output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683577/prevent-node-js-repl-from-printing-output)

Comment: Thanks, @esqew, but no, that doesn't solve the problem. I think that only prevents an output from being printed. The problem is not that the output is being printed; it's that the interpreter is trying to evaluate my statement before I finish typing it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, I use this in class but I hate that it shows the answers before I ask the question.

Comment: @AndrewS Unfortunately, no, I never found an answer. :( The only thing that works for me is making sure that my statement is syntactically invalid until I'm ready to execute it. For example, if you wanted to type `add(1, 2)`, you could either type `add()` (i.e., closing the parentheses first) and then go back and insert the 1 and 2, or you could type each character from left-to-right without closing the parentheses first. In the latter case, the statement is invalid until the last character, so the interpreter doesn't attempt to execute it earlier.

Comment: I'll put in a feature request in their Gut Hub repo.

Answer (score 4):

The [REPL library](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl) calls that a preview (search for `preview` in the link for more info). I'm not aware how to launch the default node REPL with command line options (or some other kind of configuration options) so that previews are not shown, but the REPL itself is a library you can use, with all the defaults (or whatever you prefer) and removing previews - for this check the [REPL library options](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#replstartoptions).

A basic example is creating this script:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const repl = require('repl');

repl.start({
  preview: false
});
```

Make sure you also have it as executable (in Linux/Mac from the command line it would be with `chmod +x name-of-repl-script` from the terminal), and well, run that script instead of `node` directly.
Alternatively you can run the script with `node name-of-repl-script` (here, assuming `node` is the NodeJS REPL executable and that it's in the path).

Comment: What about if I just start REPL from the command line (i.e. $> nodejs) and do not want it to show previews

Comment: You can create a script as the one posted and use it instead of the default `nodejs`. Unless an option is later added, that's the only way I know. There's a PR about this: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3967 (the solution proposed is essentially this script).